# CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer is saying both user and bot in a chatbot

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, bots

Hello guys I'm building a chatbot with MicrosoftBot Framework and I want to enable speech synthetizer but only for the bot answers.

to enable the speech I have this options

```
// use browser built in capabilities for TTS/STT
const speechOptions = {
  speechRecognizer: new this.CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: speechRecognizerKey }),
  speechSynthesizer: new this.CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({
    gender: this.CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
    subscriptionKey: speechSynthesizerKey,
    voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
  })
};
```

and then I pass the speech options to the bot start up configuration

```
// BotChat is exposed by the botchat.js
// When we run this line, the botchat.js has to be loaded in the page.
this.BotChat.App({
  bot: bot,
  locale: params['locale'],
  resize: 'detect',
  botConnection: botConnection,
  speechOptions: speechOptions,
  user: user
}, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere'));
```

So my question is, is there any option I can give to the bot framework to just say the answers and not the questions I'm doing?

Comment: I don't much understand your request, as on my side, I need  to click the mic icon to speek to bot, then the web chat will respond via voice.

Comment: Using the generic code, the bot created is simply an echo bot, replying with what the user says. Can you clarify what you mean by 'saying both user and bot'? Do you mean, if you say into a mic "Hello Echo Bot", does it say back "Hello Echo Bot you said Hello Echo Bot"?  Or does it simply say "You said" and what the user said to it?